# USB/IP emulated device not listed by libusb

Tags: ip, usb

There's [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) tool which allows share access USB devices over TCP/IP network. USB device connected to Linux PC which running TCP server and Windows PC running VHCI driver which connects to Linux.
This approach makes possible to emulate any USB device without hardware at all. All you need is write TCP server which will handle USB requests. (like [here](http://breaking-the-system.blogspot.com/2014/08/emulating-usb-devices-in-python-with-no.html))

But the problem with it that emulated device is not really correct. When you try to list connected USB devices using **libusb** you'll get an error *'unlisted ancestor for..'* since emulated device has no parent in device-tree. 
From other hand some tools like [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) show emulated device.

Exactly problem discussed [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libusb/mailman/libusb-devel/thread/55198381.5040109@probo.com/) and no real solution provided.

So question is it bug in USB/IP windows driver? Can anybody experienced with Windows drivers development helps? What's a deal about parent device? Why it is so important?

Any hint will be very very appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance for any help

UDPATE : technically problem is that parent of emulated device (USB/IP enumerator) not recognized by libusb as HUB. This makes emulated devices ignored due-to NULL parent. So question is how to patch USB/IP driver to be visible by libusb as normal USB HUB

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that USB/IP windows driver v0.2.0.0 does not reply on  *IRP_MN_QUERY_CAPABILITIES* IRPs. It dispatch only *IRP_MN_QUERY_CAPABILITIES* targeted on emulated devices, but not to bus driver itself.
I have added *IRP_MN_QUERY_CAPABILITIES* processing to USB/IP driver and now it is detected by **libusb** as normal USB HUB device.

UPD:

in *pnp.c* inside method

```
 NTSTATUS Bus_FDO_PnP (
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT       DeviceObject,
    __in PIRP                 Irp,
    __in PIO_STACK_LOCATION   IrpStack,
    __in PFDO_DEVICE_DATA     DeviceData )
```

I have added new 'case' inside `switch (IrpStack->MinorFunction)` :

```
case IRP_MN_QUERY_CAPABILITIES:
{
    status = _PDO_QueryDeviceCaps(DeviceData, Irp);

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    Bus_DecIoCount(DeviceData);
    return status;
}
```

**UPD2: and also this:**

```
NTSTATUS _PDO_QueryDeviceCaps(__in PFDO_DEVICE_DATA DeviceData, __in PIRP Irp)
{
PIO_STACK_LOCATION      stack;
PDEVICE_CAPABILITIES    deviceCapabilities;
DEVICE_CAPABILITIES     parentCapabilities;

PAGED_CODE();

stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
deviceCapabilities = stack->Parameters.DeviceCapabilities.Capabilities;

if (deviceCapabilities->Version != 1 || deviceCapabilities->Size < sizeof(DEVICE_CAPABILITIES))
{
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemWorking] = PowerDeviceD0;

if (deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping1] != PowerDeviceD0)
    deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping1] = PowerDeviceD1;

if (deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping2] != PowerDeviceD0)
    deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping2] = PowerDeviceD3;

if (deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping3] != PowerDeviceD0)
    deviceCapabilities->DeviceState[PowerSystemSleeping3] = PowerDeviceD3;

deviceCapabilities->DeviceWake = PowerDeviceD1;

deviceCapabilities->DeviceD1 = TRUE; // Yes we can
deviceCapabilities->DeviceD2 = FALSE;

deviceCapabilities->WakeFromD0 = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->WakeFromD1 = TRUE; 
deviceCapabilities->WakeFromD2 = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->WakeFromD3 = FALSE;

deviceCapabilities->D1Latency = 0;
deviceCapabilities->D2Latency = 0;
deviceCapabilities->D3Latency = 0;

deviceCapabilities->EjectSupported = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->HardwareDisabled = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->Removable = TRUE;

deviceCapabilities->SurpriseRemovalOK = TRUE;
deviceCapabilities->UniqueID = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->SilentInstall = FALSE;
deviceCapabilities->Address = 1;
deviceCapabilities->UINumber = 1;

return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to share the source to that change? A bunch of USB debugging tools don't seem to work or see, like in your case, with USB/IP and I'm trying to emulate a device with it.

Comment: Thank you! That's extremely helpful.

Comment: Is that `Bus_PDO_QueryDeviceCaps`?

Comment: no, it is Bus_FDO_PnP() called from Bus_PnP(). or what do you mean?

Comment: The line with `status = _PDO_QueryDeviceCaps`. Is `_PDO_QueryDeviceCaps` defined?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add it. Now done. also in busenum.h add NTSTATUS _PDO_QueryDeviceCaps(__in PFDO_DEVICE_DATA DeviceData, __in PIRP Irp);